# PC (java program) and Android communication over USB

Tags: java, android, usb, client-server

I need to develop android application that will communicate with PC over USB. The PC software will send some data and android app need to display received data.

I already did this communication over sockets (pc server, android client), but i need to cover situation if there is no internet connection. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You dont need internet if a router is used to connect the two.

Comment: @blackapps Could you explain it a little bit more?
Also, i need to cover situation if there is no internet connection at all (without router), but i would like to know more about suggestion you wrote too. Thank you

Comment: What is there to explain? Are you using a router now with internet? Then detach the incoming -internet- cable. Leave the router on. And everything continous to work as before. Only that you have no internet then. But your devices can still communicate. You only use LAN.

Comment: @blackapps Thank you for explanation. What if my PC is connected to router with cable, and my router doesn't have wireless connection, so android device can not connect to it? On the other hand android device is connected with PC over USB cable and use that connection to power up. I need to cover that possibility too and use this USB connection to send data to android device